# Tensorflow c++ api failed set gpu/cpu number: SetDefaultDevice error: Duplicate registration of device factory for type GPU with the same priority 210

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I am loading a trianed tensorflow model and runs it. When I try to set the gpu number, an error raises.

> F tensorflow/core/common_runtime/device_factory.cc:77] Duplicate
>   registration of device factory for type GPU with the same priority 210

Code I use is like:

```
tensorflow::GraphDef graph_def;
tensorflow::Status graphLoadedStatus = ReadBinaryProto(tensorflow::Env::Default(),model_path, &graph_def);
if (!graphLoadedStatus.ok()) {
    std::cerr <<"Model path : " << graphLoadedStatus.ToString() << std::endl;
    return graphLoadedStatus;
}

// set device to be on gpu
tensorflow::graph::SetDefaultDevice("/gpu:3", &graph_def);
```

Google it and no result except the tensoeflow's source code: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/device_factory.cc

Any one have met this? Or can tf's contributor give me some clues?

It looks like a problem of priority, so I tried to run with root, but no use.

Btw, I am using c++. If I use python, I can set the gpu number with no error.

Answer (score 1):

I rebuild tensorflow from the source and use the new libtensorflow_cc.so and head files. Then this problem vanishes.

I think this is caused by my libtensorflow_cc.so and head files are not the same version.